# Что говорят стандарты про изменение состояния не константного объекта и видимость этих изменений через указатель на константу?

Tags: c++, c, const

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что стандарты языков `C` и `C++` говорят про следующую ситуацию:

Допустим, есть статический не константный объект:

```
static Object object;
```

Я хочу использовать его в качестве промежуточного буфера, в который библиотека выкладывает результаты работы своих функций. Для этого, я предоставляю пользователю функцию, через которую он может получить указатель на этот объект:

```
const Object* get_object()
{
    return &object;
}
```

При этом, я возвращаю пользователю указатель на константное значение, чтобы пользователь мог лишь читать из этого объекта.

Работа с библиотекой может осуществляться так:

```
const Object*const object = get_object();

do_something_1();

// Read info from object.

do_something_2();

// Read info from object again.
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, верно ли я понимаю, что пользователь не сможет менять состояние объекта, но, при этом, состояние объекта сможет меняться через библиотеку, поскольку изначальный объект является изменяемым? Не нарушается ли в этом случае какое-нибудь правило стандарта? Может ли компилятор решить, что объект, на который указывает указатель на неизменяемое значение, не менялся?

Comment: Ну как минимум `return &object;`, раз уж возвращаете указатель...

Comment: Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: *"Может ли компилятор решить, что объект, на который указывает указатель на неизменяемое значение, не менялся?"* - к сожалению, не может. *"пользователь не сможет менять состояние объекта"* - к сожалению, может.

Answer (score 2):

С помощью `const_cast` пользователь может получить указатель на объект без квалификатора `const`  и поменять объект. При этом не будет неопределенного поведения, т.к. объект изначально не объявлен константным.

```
Object * p = const_cast<Object*>(get_object());
//Законно изменяем объект через p
```

Вопрос в том, насколько вы сами хотите защищать этот объект от изменения. Зачастую, возврата указателя на константный объект вполне достаточно.

Comment: Вопрос заключается не в этом. Вопрос заключается в том, позволяет ли стандарт ожидать изменение объекта через указатель на константу?

Comment: @MGNeo я же написал, что неопределенного поведения не будет, стандарт позволяет изменять неконстантный объект через указатель на константу.

Comment: вы не поняли моего вопроса. Я спрашиваю не об этом.

Comment: @MGNeo я, вроде, понимаю о чем вы спрашиваете. Если вы отдадите куда-то ссылку/указатель на не константный объект, его там *могут законно поменять*, независимо от наличия const-квалификации. Что касается константности указателя, то https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const.cast#6 В стандарте на этот счет даже пример имеется: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4 - смотрите на манипуляции с указателем ip. Так что да, стандарт позволяет так менять объекты, а значит такое поведение ожидаемо.

Comment: То есть, стандарт дает гарантии, что если я поменяю изначальный не константный объект, то эти изменения будут видны через указатель на константу, который получен до операции, которая изменила изначальный не константный объект?

Comment: @MGNeo А попробуйте объявить его `volatile`, если есть такая возможность его изменения. Для того он, вроде, и предназначен.

Comment: @Harry, с `volatile` все понятно. Но я хочу понять, позволяет ли стандарт увидеть сам факт изменения не константного объекта через указатель или ссылку на константный объект.